# The camel-challenge

Tags: situation

A sheik had two sons. He loved them both very much, but he had to choose one heir. So he called both and said to them:

> "Take your best camels and ride to the oasis, which is is the farthest
>   in my realm. My heir will be whose camel is the last to arrive at my
>   palace."

The sons take their camels and rode together to the oasis slowly. But when they were there, they realized that they had a problem. Both of them wanted to be heir so they could not make a decision. But, after a while, an enchantress appeared and asked them, why they looked so sad. The sons told her their problem and the enchantress whispered something in both ears. Only seconds later, two camels left the oasis and ran to the palace of the sheik.
What did the enchantress whispered to the sons?

(Remark: I translated this puzzle, which my grandfather told to me when I was a child, out of the german language. I'm afraid that my translation isn't 100% equal to the original puzzle, but I hope you have some fun anyway.)

### Edit:

Yes, this is a duplicate. I searched for a duplecate before i asked this question, but I didn't found the original. You can exchange animals and persons and then the puzzle is exactly the same.

Comment: Did the camels arrive at the same time?

Comment: @BaileyM it does look like it

Comment: How did the sons get back without their camels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but:

> If they both agree to switch camels it turns into a race instead and they don't have to wait at the oasis until they die. But at the same time if one of them isn't as good a rider as the other, then he'd be a bit stupid to agree...

Answer (score 1):

She either said :

> "Send your brother's camel."

OR...

> "Dudes, just send both at the same time."